# BlockingQueue Behaviour for Multiple Request

Tags: java, multithreading, servlets, queue, blockingqueue

I am Sorry if my Question is Silly.

I am using ArrayBlockingQueue.

```
private ArrayBlockingQueue<RequestParameters> processorQueue;
private int sizeOfQueue = 3000;
```

Here, my Producer is seperate thread and Consumer is seperate Thread.
both are running in Single Producer-Consumer Thread model.

Now, I am running my Java App, which gives request to my Servlet. Producer put the request in Queue.
Consumer pics the request and start processing, which involves DB operations.(takes around 1 second to complete task)

Here, My Producer is getting request very fast and it fills Queue and wait until consumer start processing and make space in Queue.

My Question here is

1. What best BlockingQueue Impl I should use, So that I will get best Performance.
2. What will happen when Queue Size is Full, I mean Servlet will get request irrespective of Producer is waiting for Queue to get Vaccant. What about all those incoming Request? Where those request will go? are those request be 
   stored in JVM Memory and given to Producer Thread once it is non-blocking?

Thanks.

Comment: Why don't you use an `ExecutorService`?

Comment: you mean to say, to create more then 1 thread for consumer threads and maintain a Thread pool for Consumer Threads?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Though right solution will depend upon the fesibility of your application requirement, following might be helpful:

When Q is full instead of blocking indefinitely, block with `timeout` so as servlet will return response in a fix configured time. In case of `timeout`, servlet can throw server-busy kind of custom error message or related `HTTP-CODE`.

Since your consumer is slow and producer is very fast, you might as well consider increasing consumer threads so as to allow lesser blocking experience to servlet caller.

Also, accepting all request (ie storing into a unbounded-Q) wouldn't be a nice solution as (depending upon request size) due to slow consumer Q, over period of time might consume huge memory..

Comment: That's what my second Question was, If my Queue is bounded say size 2000 then in this case producer Thread will accept till that point? what happen when it is full and try to make a call put(). I understands that it blocks, but what about the request which is still coming to Servlet, where such request will go? what about those? are those get stored in temp memory, because once producer find space it takes next request, so how it get that previous request which already came long time back.

Comment: once `put` starts to block, all new request will endup having request-threads lying waiting for put. Now since typically all web-server has a upper limit on max-request-threads (ie tomcat configures this in server.xml), once that limit will reach, server will throw `server-unavailable` or `out-of-resoruce` kind of error message to futher new requests. So, request (or request data) would get store in its thread as local variables (in stack) until `put` un-blocks..

Answer (score 1):

1) Don't use concrete implementations as types of fields or variables of return types of methods and etc. Use interfaces or abstract classes instead. In your case such class will be just `BlockingQueue`:

`private BlockingQueue<RequestParameters> processorQueue = ...`

2) You do not need to have additional field `sizeOfQueue` - you will pass its value into constructor of `processorQueue`.

3) Finally, you can use `LinkedBlockingQueue` implementation for such purposes:

`private BlockingQueue<RequestParameters> processorQueue = new LinkedBlockingQueue(300);`

Comment: Very nice but doesn't answer either of the actual questions. -1

Answer (score 1):

> What best BlockingQueue Impl I should use, So that I will get best Performance.

I'd be astonished if it made any difference given that you have a network in the system, but you should look to use one based on a linked list if FIFO performance is your criterion and there is no random access.

> What will happen when Queue Size is Full

You specified `BlockingQueue,` so it will block.

This is all in the Javadoc.